# Remove substring from column based on list of other column

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

This is my dataset

```
tweet                              |           url
-----------------------------------|------------------
"Hello World url1 url12"           |      [url1, url12]  
"Good morning url2 engine url41"   |      [url2, url41]
"Nice to meet you url3         "   |      [url3]
"You are fantastic "               |      []
```

*Please consider that url1,url2... is a representation of real URLs.*

I would like to iterate over the column **url** and look for these URLs in the corresponding row of "tweet" then remove from my column tweet all the URLs and create a new clean column.

At first I tried with this code

```
ds['urls_free_tweet'] = ds.apply(lambda row :  row['tweet'].replace(str(row['url']), ''), axis=1)
```

But this code is not considering all the URLs given in the array of the column "url".

Expected result

```
tweet                              |           url        |    urls_free_tweet
-----------------------------------|----------------------|--------------------- 
"Hello World url1 url12"           |      [url1, url12]   |      "Hello World
"Good morning url2 engine url41"   |      [url2, url41]   |      "Good morning engine"
"Nice to meet you url3         "   |      [url3]          |      "Nice to meet you"
"You are fantastic "               |      []              |      "You are fantastic "
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear whether or not your data is coming in as a list, a DataFrame, or something else. So I am going to show you a solution that can be used for either, just iterate over the data and in each iteration over your data use the following logic. Replace **str** and **url** variables with the value of your data for the current iteration.

```
str = "Hello world url1 url2"
url = "url1 url2"
removed = str.split(url)
final = ("").join(removed).strip()
```

Comment: Yes my data is a data frame and the column "url" is a list of URLs that I would like to remove.  ```must be str or None, not list ``` this is the result that I got if I try url = ["url1", "url2"]

Comment: Yeah url is supposed to be a string... so iterate over url = ["url1", "url2"], i.e. for each in url_list: url = each

Answer (score 0):

You can join the list as a string with the `|` symbol and replace row by row with `re.sub`, since you need to compare values from each row of each column against each other. To vectorize, it would only work if you could have a list of all URLs for the entire dataframe and replace all at once that way, but I'm not sure if that is what -- so a row-by-row comparison may be necessary:

Input:

```
import pandas
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({'tweet': {0: 'Hello World url1 url12',
  1: 'Good morning url2 engine url41',
  2: 'Nice to meet you url3         ',
  3: 'You are fantastic '},
 'url': {0: ['url1', 'url12 '], 1: ['url2', 'url41'], 2: ['url3'], 3: [' ']}})
```

---

Code:

```
df['url'] = df['url'].str.join('|').str.strip()
df['tweet'] = (df.apply(lambda x: re.sub(x['url'], '', x['tweet']), axis=1)
                 .str.strip().str.replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True))
```

---

Output:

```
df
Out[1]: 
                        tweet         url
0              Hello World 2  url1|url12
1       Good morning engine    url2|url41
2  Nice to meet you                  url3
3          You are fantastic
```

If you want `url` back as a list at the end, then you can do `df['url'] = df['url'].str.split('|')`

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be simplistic as Below:

```
df['tweet'].str.replace('url.*', '')
0          Hello World
1         Good morning
2     Nice to meet you
3    You are fantastic
```

OR

```
df['urls_free_tweet'] = df['tweet'].str.replace('url.*', '')
print(df)
                            tweet             url    urls_free_tweet
0          Hello World url1 url12  [url1, url12 ]        Hello World
1  Good morning url2 engine url41   [url2, url41]       Good morning
2  Nice to meet you url3                   [url3]   Nice to meet you
3              You are fantastic              [ ]  You are fantastic
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `re` re find and replace whole word matches from the url list.

```
df.apply(lambda x: re.compile('|'.join([r'\b' + re.escape(e) + r'\b' for e in x.url])).sub('', x.tweet), axis=1)
```

The `r'\b'` part in the pattern is important. If removed, `Hello World url1 url12` will be converted to `Hello World 2` instead of `Hello World` as the `url1` part in `url12` will be replaced first therefore part of that url will not be replaced.